# How to create a list with descriptions in pdftooltip

Tags: etoolbox

What I wish is simply to create a list in latex which contains variable names and a description and use it for pdftoolTip. This should be seen in the context of \begin{equation} enviroment.

So the list should be: 
Variable name: x Description "x is long".
Variable name: y Description "y is not".

I made this work using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn, oneside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

\newcommand{\definelement}[2]{%
  \newtoggle{#1}%
  \toggletrue{#1}%
  \csdef{#1desc}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\des}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{#1}{%
    \pdftooltip{#1}{\csuse{#1desc}}%
  }{%
    #1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\definelement{x}{Scalar}
\begin{equation}
    \des{x} = 100
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

\bm is just an example, could be another formatting of symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add your used documentclass to your given code snippet to make it compilable.

Comment: Thank you. I have added that

Comment: Do you, for example, want `\bm` as part of the `\definelement` or only part of the `\des` typesetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether you are asking, for example, to have `\bm` used as part of the `\definelement` or only as part of the `\des` typesetting.

Here, it may be specified as part of the `\definelement`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, flegn, oneside, openany, table, colorlinks=true]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\definelement}[2]{%
  \newtoggle{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \toggletrue{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \csdef{\detokenize{#1}desc}{#2}%
}

%\des
\newcommand{\des}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{\detokenize{#1}}{%
    \pdftooltip{#1}{\csuse{\detokenize{#1}desc}}%
  }{%
    #1%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\definelement{\bm{x}}{Scalar}
\begin{equation}
    \des{\bm{x}} = 100
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Whereas, here, it is only used as part of the `\des` typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, flegn, oneside, openany, table, colorlinks=true]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\definelement}[2]{%
  \newtoggle{#1}%
  \toggletrue{#1}%
  \csdef{#1desc}{#2}%
}

%\des
\newcommand{\des}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{#1}{%
    \pdftooltip{\bm{#1}}{\csuse{#1desc}}%
  }{%
    #1%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\definelement{x}{Scalar}
\begin{equation}
    \des{x} = 100
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In either case, the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The first part of your comment was exactly what I wanted and give the desired result :)

Comment: Do you know if there are an alternative to pdftooltip that works the same way but works in more standard pdf viewers like Chrome, Safari etc.?

Comment: Another following question is that the pdftooltip i want to be able to write R^2